# How to resolve environment variables with NET core on mac / linux?

Tags: .net-core

With NET Core 2.1 I am unable to handle environment variables on a mac or linux.

`var fullPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("$HOME/myfolder");
var exists = Directory.Exists("$HOME/myfolder");`

In fullPath, the environment variables are not expanded. Exists is false while the folder does exist. How to deal with this on a mac / linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done exactly the same way as it works on Windows (cross platform portability!):

```
var fullPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOME%/myfolder");
var exists = Directory.Exists(fullPath);
```

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-2.1) which says:

> Each environment variable is quoted with the percent sign character (%).